# How to convert Activities to Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm new to android programming pls help. It's just that I have this application modules created in Activities form. Now that I wanted to use the Android navigation bar to navigate between them, I can't do so, it seems that theres alot of things I would have to change such as the imports, the declarations, and omit certain methods etc. Is there a comprehensive manual for such task?. I just can't seem to find one. If there is, it's just limited to a few things. BTW, I just want to know how I would be able to do such task. If there is a for Dummies of it,would be the best.
Be better if it would also include the AppCompatActivity thing, I can't seem to combine it too with Fragments and Activities, :(.

Comment: You can check this tutorial - http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand your app's architecture first. You need to analyse the flow of UI screens and the underlying logic they perform. If you want to navigate through your activities using Navigation Drawer, well, then converting all of them them into fragments isn't a solution! First find out which screens can perform flawlessly if you replace them with fragments and then go ahead with it. If you are new to android programming then visit Udacity online and watch all of their android tutorial videos! They have a bunch of comprehensive ones and the best part - it's free.